# Bypassing Login screen

Tags: java, authentication, swt, eclipse-rcp

In our rcp application, we have implemented the Login feature by using the eclipse framework (Login feature on the Splash screen).

Now how do we bypass this login (including the splash screen) by providing the VM arguments?

If the VM arguments are provided with correct userName and password, we don't want to show the login page (this includes the splash screen, because login feature is on the splash screen itself)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The splash screen login dialog is implemented by using a SplashScreenHandler. This is actually added to your Application bundle. It should be relatively easy to look at the source code for your splash screen handler and add the VM arguments there.

You could also just disable the splash screen using the `-noSplash` command-line option.

Comment: i was referring to pass the VM arguments from the Run configuration and see if the eclipse framework bypass the login page by itself

Comment: See http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html

Comment: The option you are looking for is '-noSplash'

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it possible to skip splash screen (also, don't see any good reason for doing so), but you could skip showing the login dialog, if you would split it from the splash screen.

Create your dialog on application startup, somehow like that:

```
Application implements IApplication {

@Override
public Object start(IApplicationContext context) throws Exception {
    Display display = PlatformUI.createDisplay();
    try {

        LoginDialog dialog = new LoginDialog(display.getActiveShell());
        if (dialog.open() == Dialog.CANCEL) {
            return EXIT_OK;
        }

        int code = PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(display, new ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor());

        // Exit the application with an appropriate return code.
        return code == PlatformUI.RETURN_RESTART ? EXIT_RESTART : EXIT_OK;

    } finally {

        if (display != null) {
            display.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

You could then skip showing the dialog by checking required system properties and authenticate user with properties values:

```
    String username = System.getProperty("username");
    String pwd = System.getProperty("password");
    if (username != null && pwd != null) {
        // do something with username and password
    } else {
         LoginDialog dialog = new LoginDialog(display.getActiveShell());
         if (dialog.open() == Dialog.CANCEL) {
             return EXIT_OK;
          }
     }
```

Also, `Platform.endSplash();` Might be helpful.

Comment: oh well, i was able to skip the login part but not the splash screen itself. Because, before the control comes to Application's start method, splash will be poping! So even though i call Platform.endSplash() in the start method, it has no effects! Thanks for your pointers

Comment: May be you could try to create a custom splash handler, which would not be shown (or could be closed early)? Otherwise, as I've mentioned before, there are probably no way to skip conditionally splash.

Comment: yeah, may be i need to check that. Anyways, thanks for the suggestions